# Mapping device memory for Linux 2.6.30 DMA API

Tags: linux, arm, dma, memory-mapping

I've been struggling with this one, would really appreciate some help. I want to use the internal SRAM (stepping stone - not used after boot) of my At91sam9g45 to speed up some intensive computations and am having trouble meeting all the following conditions:

1. Memory is accessible from user space. This was easy using the user space `mmap()` and then kernel `remap_pfn_range()`. Using the pointer returned, my user space programs can read/write to the SRAM.
2. Using the kernel DMA API call `dma_async_memcpy_buf_to_buf()` to do a memcpy using DMA. Within my basic driver, I want to call this operation to copy data from DDR( allocated with kmalloc()) into the SRAM buffer.

So my problem is that I have the user space and physical addresses, but no kernel-space DMA API friendly mapping.

I've tried using ioremap and using the fixed virutal address provided to `iotable_init()`. None of these seems to result in a kernel virtual address that can be used with something like `virt_to_bus` (which works for the kmalloc addresses and i think is used within the DMA API).

There's way around and thats just triggering the DMA manually using the physical addresses, but I'd like to try and figure this out. I've been reading through LDD3 and googling, but i can't see any examples of using non-kmalloc memory for the DMA API (except for PCI buses).

Comment: Can't you utilize [sendfile or splice](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/06/01/zero-copy-in-linux-with-sendfile-and-splice/)?

Comment: I imagine that some of that SRAM space is being used for the processor exception table and what not.  I'm not sure of all the details, but the kernel may really dislike you exposing it in this way.  You also said "user space programs"... I don't know how you plan on having more than one program accessing the space at a time, but it needs to be carefully thought out.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The SRAM isn't being used (I've verified this - only used at boottime). The reason for using it is that SRAM I/O operates at near the CPU speed rather than 133MHz of system ram. For doing lookup table calculations (FIR filter) this works much quicker. There will be only one thread using this. The processor can also yield while waiting for the DMA to finish and let other processes run.